# c# dynamic checkboxes creating

Tags: c#, checkbox

I am trying to create dynamic checkboxes in a for loop. But I am getting error not during compiling but when I run create checkbox button and run that function.
Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
 public void CreateCheckBox (int i)
         {
              int y = 10;
              CheckBox[] _cb = new CheckBox[i];
              String chkBox = "chkBox_";
              for (int n = 0; n<i; n++)
                    {
                       _cb[n].Location = new Point(10, y);
                       _cb[n].Name= chkBox + n.ToString();
                       form1.Controls.Add(_cb[n]);
                       y+= 15;
                    }
         }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside the loop, you'll have to create a new instance of checkbox.

```
for (int n = 0; n<i; n++)
{
   _cb[n] = new CheckBox();
   _cb[n].Location = new Point(10, y);
   _cb[n].Name= chkBox + n.ToString();
   form1.Controls.Add(_cb[n]);
   y+= 15;
}
```

Comment: Bala what if I want to delete on of these checkboxes? how can I create a form1.Controls.Remove() thing?

Comment: @ValNolav to remove, you can do `Control cb = form1.FindControl(controlName); form1.Controls.Remove(cb);`

Answer (score 0):

When you define an `Array` of `Checkboxes`, the objects inside the array are initialized to `null`. You need to create an instance of the Checkbox using `new Checkbox()`.

In my opinion, you don't need to save them into a `Checkbox[]` since the Form manages a control collection. So, this code snippet is maybe more readable:

```
public void CreateCheckBox (int max)
{
    String name = "chkBox_";
    int y = 10;
    for (int i = 0; n < max; i++)
    {
        Checkbox current = new Checkbox();
        current.Location = new Point(10, y);
        current.Name= name + i.ToString();
        form1.Controls.Add(current);
        y+= 15;
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to delete textboxes in a row by clicking checkbox in the same row. How can I do that by clicking a button??

Comment: I recommend you to store the row index in the checkbox.Tag, then you listen the CheckedChanged event in the textbox (using += ) and in the Event handler, take the row index from the tag of the sender.